# Copying background color from cells on a different tab of the same sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Google Sheets I have two tabs with different information. Tab A has a table I am using as a summary of variables per person. Tab B has the color coding of each of the variables in a random order. What I am trying to achieve is to have the summary table on Tab A be linked to the colour coding on tab B. So whenever the color of each variable changes on Tab B it will change on Tab A as well.

[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tsu75.png)

Is it possible to keep the typed value inside the cells of Tab A but copy the color coding (background color) in Tab B?

I think the only way would be with a custom function or script.

I tried with conditional formatting however the problem is that I can only get it to work if all the data is on the same tab.

Comment: Custom formulas in conditional formatting _can_ refer to another sheet, you just need to wrap such cell references in `indirect`. So, instead of something like `=Sheet2!A3>Sheet3!B4` you would have `=indirect("Sheet2!A3") > indirect("Sheet3!B4")`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. However I am still having trouble translating being able to reference that cell into copying the color of cells on Sheet A to Sheet B.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should do what you want. It will also handle adding people and vehicles. I am also sharing the spreadsheet I tested it on.

```
function colorCode() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var lr=ss.getSheets()[0].getLastRow() // get last row of sheet1
  var lc=ss.getSheets()[0].getLastColumn() //get last column of sheet1
  var lr1=ss.getSheets()[1].getLastRow() // get last row of sheet2
  var lc1=ss.getSheets()[1].getLastColumn() ////get last column of sheet2
  var sv=ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(1,2,1,lc-1).getValues() // get vehicles
  var sn=ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(2,1,lr-1,1).getValues() // get names
  var s1=ss.getSheets()[1].getRange(2,1,lr,lc-1)//exclude lehend
  var rng1=s1.getValues() // get sheet2 data
  var rng2=s1.getBackgrounds() // get background colors of dheet2 data

  var col=1 //column for vehicles om sheet1
   for(var m=0;m<sv[0].length;m++){ //for each vehicle
      col=col+1 //add one to vehicle column
  for(var n=0;n<sn.length;n++){ //for each name
  for(var i=0;i<sn.length;i++){ //loop sheet2 data
  for(var j=0;j<rng1[0].length;j++){
    if(rng1[i][j].indexOf(sv[0][m])>-1 && rng1[i][j].indexOf(sn[n][0])>-1){ //if sheet2 data cell contains vehicle and name
       var c=ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(n+2, col).setBackground(rng2[i][j]) //set color of vehicle and name on sheet1
  }}}}}
}
```

Test spreadsheet:

```
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/13zudMf86oOXHMSYg6rJGPguNfRxCr0aUHAktr0RqWzY/edit?usp=sharing
```

To shift the table on sheet1 down 4 rows use this. The changes are noted in the code.

```
function colorCode() {
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var lr=ss.getSheets()[0].getLastRow() // get last row of sheet1
  var lc=ss.getSheets()[0].getLastColumn() //get last column of sheet1
  var lr1=ss.getSheets()[1].getLastRow() // get last row of sheet2
  var lc1=ss.getSheets()[1].getLastColumn() ////get last column of sheet2
  var sv=ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(5,2,1,lc-1).getValues() // get vehicles//CHANGED 1 tp 5
  var sn=ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(6,1,lr-5,1).getValues() // get names//CHANGED 2 to 6 and -1 to -5
  var s1=ss.getSheets()[1].getRange(2,1,lr,lc-1)//exclude legend
  var rng1=s1.getValues() // get sheet2 data
  var rng2=s1.getBackgrounds() // get background colors of sheet2 data

 var col=1 //column for vehicles on sheet1
   for(var m=0;m<sv[0].length;m++){ //for each vehicle
      col=col+1 //add one to vehicle column
  for(var n=0;n<sn.length;n++){ //for each name
  for(var i=0;i<sn.length;i++){ //loop sheet2 data
  for(var j=0;j<rng1[0].length;j++){
    if(rng1[i][j].indexOf(sv[0][m])>-1 && rng1[i][j].indexOf(sn[n][0])>-1){   //if sheet2 data cell contains vehicle and name
       var c=ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(n+6, col).setBackground(rng2[i][j]) //set color of vehicle and name on sheet1//CHANGED +2 to +6
  }}}}}
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much this is perfect :). I also really appreciate the comments in the code to help me learn.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, I just have one more question. I am trying to shift the table on sheet1 down 4 rows. I thought that if i changed the start row and column like this.

`var sv=ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(5,2,1,lc-1).getValues() // get vehicles
  
var sn=ss.getSheets()[0].getRange(6,1,lr-1,1).getValues() // get names`
I thought that this would work in shifting the table down but when I run the script some of the colors are repeated multiple times along the column.

Comment: Forgot to tag in the above comment @EdNelson

Comment: @Thomas Gardner See addition to answer.

Comment: Oh I forgot to change that n+2 to n+6, thanks :). I just have one last question. When I run the script on a sheet that is populated by many rows (about 70 rows of people). The script has a hard time running compared to on a smaller scale. It takes about 20-60seconds to finish by itself, I have a feeling its getting stuck somewhere or looping more times than needed. If I cancel the script a few seconds after it finishes naturally, it still works and fills in the cells that it should. @EdNelson

Comment: @Thomas Gardner If you can post a sample sheet, I will take a look.

Comment: Here is an example of the sheet I am using your script on. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/11ZMu9-vf9Ug9dO2rCmTs13LR45cvmoMUzq-Zn6rozZE/edit?usp=sharing. The Monday Tab will have the result of the script. It took about 40s to finish. If you cant find anything wrong with it, its not a big deal I was just wondering if it was me who did something wrong.

Comment: sorry forgot to tag again :(.

Comment: wouldn't let me edit the above comment, sorry for double post @EdNelson

Comment: @Thomas Gardner This speeds it up .https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Bi5InUdUvZZ2dF8tl55Pi5rtGTUniiiJqS4Euh4C6eM/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: awesome, thanks for all the time and effort you put in to help me, I really appreciate it :D.